# AJAX not being called when select box changed

Tags: php, jquery

I am using jquery to call a PHP script when a select box changes. I am able to get the ID of the select item that changes, however I get no output from the PHP script. The Javascript is

```
function initagents() {
  $('select.agent').on('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(id);
    var data = { id: id };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "updateagent.php",
      data: data 
    }).done(function(msg) {
      console.log(msg);
    });
  });
}
```

and the PHP is

```
print_r ( $_POST);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked in the console to ensure that the AJAX request was successful?

Comment: Also note that your title says the request isn't being made, but the question says you get nothing back from the PHP - which is it? They are two different problems.

Comment: Do you call initagents() function anywhere? If you don't call the function on document.ready or window.load, the event listener will not be assigned

Comment: Is initagents() actually being called? I'm not sure about the context of your application but I don't think you need to wrap that .on() inside of a function.

Comment: Per your description, you should use  var id = $(this).val(); to get the selected value, not attr id code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use

```
echo json_encode($_POST['id']);
```

instead of

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made a mistake by placing the `onChange` event of the select box inside `function initagents()`.

**fixed code:**

```
$('select.agent').on('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(id);
    var data = {
        id: id
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "updateagent.php",
        data: data
    }).done(function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try with the following code:

```js
function getID(val) {
  alert(val);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'post.php',
    data: {
      id: val
    },
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<select name="pks" onchange='getID(this.value);'>
  <option value="1">Option1</option>
  <option value="2">Option2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This isn't 1996. There's no excuse for using the ugly and outdated `on*` event attributes. The only reason they still exist is for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Seems your code is correct and it should send the data to php file. But also I see that, you are not sending selected value to php script. You are posting selected element ID.

Are you trying this in a sub folder ? make sure the php file path is correct in javascript. Better if you can try with the full path. For example

```
url: "http://localhost/myproject/updateagent.php",
```